# Replace css background-url value

Tags: regex, node.js

i would like to replace the css background urls like these:

```
body {
  background: url("../common/images/image-1.jpg") center center;
}
.calss-1 { 
  background: url("./vau/image-2.png"); 
}
.class-2 { 
  background: url("./image-3.svg"); 
}
.class-3 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2MTIgNzkyIj48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjNWNiODVjIiBkPSJNMjMzLjggNjEwYy0xMy4zIDAtMjYtNi0zNC0xNi44TDkwLjUgNDQ4LjhDNzYuMyA0MzAgODAgNDAzLjMgOTguOCAzODljMTguOC0xNC4yIDQ1LjUtMTAuNCA1OS44IDguNGw3MiA5NUw0NTEuMyAyNDJjMTIuNS0yMCAzOC44LTI2LjIgNTguOC0xMy43IDIwIDEyLjQgMjYgMzguNyAxMy43IDU4LjhMMjcwIDU5MGMtNy40IDEyLTIwLjIgMTkuNC0zNC4zIDIwaC0yeiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
}
```

to these:

```
body {
  background: url("../images/image-1.jpg") center center;
}
.class-1 { 
  background: url("../images/image-2.png"); 
}
.class-2 { 
  background: url("../images/image-3.svg"); 
}
.class-3 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2MTIgNzkyIj48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjNWNiODVjIiBkPSJNMjMzLjggNjEwYy0xMy4zIDAtMjYtNi0zNC0xNi44TDkwLjUgNDQ4LjhDNzYuMyA0MzAgODAgNDAzLjMgOTguOCAzODljMTguOC0xNC4yIDQ1LjUtMTAuNCA1OS44IDguNGw3MiA5NUw0NTEuMyAyNDJjMTIuNS0yMCAzOC44LTI2LjIgNTguOC0xMy43IDIwIDEyLjQgMjYgMzguNyAxMy43IDU4LjhMMjcwIDU5MGMtNy40IDEyLTIwLjIgMTkuNC0zNC4zIDIwaC0yeiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
}
```

The api of `gulp-replace` valid javascript regular expressions without any javascript function.

This works but doesn't count in base64 encoded images: `/\((.*\/)(.*?)\)/g` replace with `("../images/$2)`.

I came up with this: `/\(([^(data)]*\/)(.*?)\)/g` the problem is, the capturing group gets messed up.

Here is an example you can play with: http://regexr.com/3cj57

Comment: You just want a regex to change that? `gulp-replace`? Do you have to do this in Node? `/\.+

Comment: yep, it supposed to be an automated task with gulp which use node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegExp is a bad way to transform CSS. Using a special CSS parser is a better way. Especially because it is easy.

You can take a [postcss-url](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-url) plugin and set custom callback to replace all `url()`.